# RoboSpice. RequestListener doesn`t fire

Tags: https, robospice

I`am using RoboSpice to receive and handle JSON answer from server. I have made all like in RoboSpice tutorial: added service(NetworkSpiceService) in AndroidManifest.xml, added needful libs, implemented a special response object - SimpleResponse with @JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown = true).

The Base Activity:

```
public abstract class BaseActivity extends Activity {

private SpiceManager spiceManager = new SpiceManager(NetworkSpiceService.class);
@Override
protected void onStart() {
    spiceManager.start(this);
    super.onStart();
}

@Override 
protected void onStop() {
    spiceManager.shouldStop();
    super.onStop();
}

public SpiceManager getSpiceManager() {
    return spiceManager;
}
```

}

My work Activity:

```
public class MainActivity extends BaseActivity implements OnClickListener{
private static final String JSON_CACHE_KEY = "some_json";
private Button button1;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    // ...
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
    return true;
}


private void load() {
    getSpiceManager().execute(NetworkManager.getJson(param), JSON_CACHE_KEY, DurationInMillis.ALWAYS_EXPIRED, new JsonRequestListener());
}

private class JsonRequestListener implements RequestListener<SimpleResponse> {


    @Override
    public void onRequestFailure(SpiceException spiceException) {
        Log.e("Json", "failure: " + spiceException.getMessage());
    }

    @Override
    public void onRequestSuccess(SimpleResponse simpleResponse) {
        Log.i("Json", "response");
        Log.i("Json", "response received. offset = " +  simpleResponse.getOffset() + " timezone = " + simpleResponse.getTimeZone());
    }

}
```

NetwokManager class:

```
public class NetworkManager {
private static final String API_KEY = ".....";
private static final String GET_SOME_URL = "https://api.servername.com/" + API_KEY + "/";

public static GetRequest<SimpleResponse> getJson(double param) {

    return new  GetRequest<SimpleResponse>(SimpleResponse.class, GET_SOME_URL + param);

}
```

}

And GetRequest:

```
public class GetRequest<T extends SimpleRequest> extends
    SpringAndroidSpiceRequest<T> {
private Class<T> clazz;
private String url;



public GetRequest(Class<T> clazz, String url) {
    super(clazz);
    this.clazz = clazz;
    this.url = url;
}


@Override
public T loadDataFromNetwork() throws Exception {
    return getRestTemplate().getForObject(url, clazz);
}
```

So, after call of load() i am expected to fire OnRequestFailure(...) or onRequestSuccess(...) , but nothing. I was convinced that loadDataFromNetwork was calling. On a browser i receive a response for that address, but not in my app.

What wrong? May be I forgot something? Or may be https request needed to be handled in some other ways?

Answer (score 0):

Where do you call `private void load()`? If it is part of the ClickListener you should be fine. If it is a method in onCreate()  you might have an issue as RoboSpice hasn't been "started" yet and is unbound so your request might be queued for execution and disregarded or returned without a reference to your listener.

Try Overriding `protected RequestListenerNotifier createRequestRequestListenerNotifier()` in your implementation of `SpiceService` and throw a bunch of breakpoints to debug in your implementation of `DefaultRequestListenerNotifier` to check what's up with the calls.

Answer (score 0):

As @Take Chances Make Cha said it, we don't see you invocation of load. It should trigger your request listener's method, at least one of the two.

Https handling in Android can become tricky if the certificate of the server is not know of Android, but this is not related to RS. That's a more general Android way of working.

Anyhow, check your logs, RS logs a lot, it will tell you what is going on, if your request is processed or not, and it will log all calls to listeners.

BTW, remove the NetworkManager static factory method, create an inheritance of request to handle common code (even constants). Such factory is not a good design, it will be impossible to mock for instance and will make testing harder.